# Get Value From Cell of a Previous Row using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Bootstrap table that when you click on the right cell, drops down an extra row and cell that links to a separate HTML file. I need to dynamically load data in here based on the value of the row that was clicked. See screen shot below:

[image]

I'm passing the value I need as a parameter into the the linked HTML file, but I need to also pass the 'Visit' number into the HTML file, but I'm not sure how to extract it dynamically.

The table is dynamically generated using this JS script

```
function buildTable($el, cells, rows) {
                $el.bootstrapTable({
                    columns: $('#VisitListTable').bootstrapTable('getOptions', null).columns,
                    detailView: cells > 1,
                    url: dataurl,
                    responseHandler: responseHandler,
                    pagination: true,
                    detailView: true,
                    detailFormatter: detailFormatter,
                    paginationVAlign: "both"
                });
            }
```

But it's outputted HTML is in a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/W3R3W0LF666/wr0bgs0g/

It's the 'Visit' number that I need to be able to pull out into a variable that I can use as and when I need to, does anyone know how I might be able to extract it so that I use a different one for a different row?

Comment: Can you post the code of the `click` event?

Comment: It's all handled by the table plugin

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://www.bootply.com/fdTMNTiLis